# SQLite group by every specific interval

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

let's assume that I have a table with entries and these entries contains timestamp column (as Long) which is telling us when that entry arrived into a table.

Now, I want to make a SELECT query, in which I want to know how many entries came in selected interval with concrete frequency.

For example: interval is from 27.10.2020 to 30.10.2020 and frequency is 6 hours. The result of the query would tell me how many entries came in this interval in 6 hour groups.

Like:

- 27.10.2020 00:00:00 - 27.10.2020 06:00:00 : 2 entries
- 27.10.2020 06:00:00 - 27.10.2020 12:00:00 : 5 entries
- 27.10.2020 12:00:00 - 27.10.2020 18:00:00 : 0 entries
- 27.10.2020 18:00:00 - 28.10.2020 00:00:00 : 11 entries
- 28.10.2020 00:00:00 - 28.10.2020 06:00:00 : 8 entries
  etc ...

The frequency parameter can be inserted in hours, days, weeks ...

Thank you all for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a recursive `CTE` like that returns the time intervals:

```
with cte as (
  select '2020-10-27 00:00:00' datestart,
         datetime('2020-10-27 00:00:00', '+6 hour') dateend
  union all
  select dateend,
         min('2020-10-30 00:00:00', datetime(dateend, '+6 hour'))
  from cte 
  where dateend < '2020-10-30 00:00:00'
)
```

Then you must do `LEFT` join of this `CTE` to the table and aggregate:

```
with cte as (
  select '2020-10-27 00:00:00' datestart,
         datetime('2020-10-27 00:00:00', '+6 hour') dateend
  union all
  select dateend,
         min('2020-10-30 00:00:00', datetime(dateend, '+6 hour'))
  from cte 
  where dateend < '2020-10-30 00:00:00'
)
select c.datestart, c.dateend, count(t.datecol) entries
from cte c left join tablename t
on datetime(t.datecol, 'unixepoch') >= c.datestart and datetime(t.datecol, 'unixepoch') < c.dateend
group by c.datestart, c.dateend
```

Replace `tablename` and `datecol` with the names of your table and date column.
If your date column contains milliseconds then change the `ON` clause to this:

```
on datetime(t.datecol / 1000, 'unixepoch') >= c.datestart 
and datetime(t.datecol / 1000, 'unixepoch') < c.dateend
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly, would you be, please, able to show me how would it be done in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=41a75008b9ef3332d45c1b548453fa06

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

```
select 
    datetime((strftime('%s', ts) / (6 * 60 * 60)) * 6 * 60 * 60, 'unixepoch') newts,
    count(*) cnt
from mytable
where ts >= '2020-10-27' and ts < '2020-10-30'
group by newts
order by newts
```

`ts` represents the datetime column in your table. SQLite does not have a `long` datatype, so this assumes that you have a legitimate date stored as `text`.

The logic of the query is to turn the date to an epoch timestamp, then round it to 6 hours, which is represented by `6 * 60 * 60`.

Comment: Date is stored in the table as a **bigint**